Replacing the user import from oidc-library to MSAL
I am working on moving from oidc to msal. What should I be doing to replace instances of the oidc-client in my project. For example, what would be the MSAL library equivalents to oicd-client imports like this:
import { UserManager, Log, User } from 'oidc-client';
Any help or direction would be helpful.
I have tried using MSAL imports such as this:
import { AccountInfo } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
But I am confused as to how that will change the project since it does not have the same properties as the User import from oidc-client

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
